# Usage of xargs and find

Tags: shell, find, xargs

I have following problem. I want to print content of several files.
Each file is in different directory, and also has same name.

```
/home/User1/data.txt
/home/User2/data.txt
/home/User3/data.txt
```

Every file contains single string. I want to achieve following output:

```
User1 string_from_data.txt
User2 string_from_data.txt
User3 string_from_data.txt
```

I've tried to use following commend:

```
find . -iname "data.txt" | xargs cat
```

but it returns only contents of each data.txt

```
string_from_data.txt
string_from_data.txt
string_from_data.txt
```

How to write it properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname "file*" -exec sh -c 'dirname $1 | xargs basename; cat $1' _ {} \;
```